# How is it possible to mount this PSU for 19' rack?

Tags: power, computer-hardware

As a part of a project I need to deliver all hardware as 2x 19" Racks. One components of the hardware is two of [these](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/LRS-75/LRS-75-spec.pdf) power supplies.

Can these supplies be fit/mounted on 19" Racks in a way? What part required to mount?

Comment: a shelf and an enclosure for the power supply

Comment: Wouldn't that question be best asked at the manufacturers?

Comment: This might be barely more on-topic at **Electrical** Engineering: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6612/custom-enclosure-design https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108791/emc-design-of-aluminium-enclosures

Comment: Can you move the question there?